# chrome and edge open offset from sides and bottom by about 10 pixels

Tags: windows, google-chrome

If I open a chrome or edge browser window that i previously closed taking up say the left side of the screen but full height it always opens 10 pixels to the right and 10 pixels from the bottom (not sure if its 10). This doesn't happen in vivaldi or any other window so im not really sure whats going on. Anyone know how to make it not do that?

pic for reference:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/4pw98PV.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

so apparently this is because chrome includes the drop shadow in its window size calculation, I guess the vivaldi programmers thought that was dumb and decided not to do that :/

https://windowresizer.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/1170-resizing-is-not-accurate-on-windows-10